# Problem in writing data to CSV file using PHP

Tags: php, csv, sorting

I have a problem on writing the data to a csv file using php. It doesn't show any error, but it didn't create the file. Can anyone help me with this?

```
<?php 
     $mdarray = array();
     $filename = basename(__FILE__, ".php");
     $f = fopen("FILES/MonitorStatus.csv", "r");
    
     while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
        array_push($mdarray, $line);
     }
     fclose($f);
    
     foreach ($mdarray as $key => $row) {
        $Status[$key]  = $row[3];
     }
    
     array_multisort($Status, SORT_ASC, $mdarray);
    
     foreach ($mdarray as $line) {
        $fp = fopen('file.csv', 'wb');
        foreach ($line as $cell) {
                fputcsv($fp, $cell);  
        }
        fclose($fp);
    }
?>
```

Comment: replace `wb` with `w` or at the very least check if `$fp` is returned as false

Comment: Also make sure you have error reporting turned on (set it as E_ALL when developing/testing). If you're working locally, you can also make sure you have "display_errors" turned on in php.ini so you get all warnings/errors directly on the page.

Comment: gets an error like this Warning: fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given @AntG

Comment: Warning: fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given @MagnusEriksson